# Android Studio - (Final) function parameters

Tags: java, android, variables, android-button, final

So I'm trying to learn Java without a proper learning source. I have a code with 3 buttons, and want to make a function with 2 parameters that would change their texts and bool variables but it seems impossible because they need to be declared final.

```
boolean btn1Check = false;
boolean btn2Check = false;
boolean btn3Check = false;

public void setButton(final Button b, final boolean check) {
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (check == true) {
                b.setText("FALSE");
                check = false; //HERE IS THE ERROR
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I don't declare those final, it gives me a different error. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you cannot change the value of a variable from an inner class. Moreover, it doesn't make sense to change the value of the `check` variable, as its scope ends with the `setButton` method execution.

If you want to change the `Button` state, you should work on the button itself, like:

```
b.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I try to help you with an explanation of your code:

```
public void setButton(final Button b, final boolean check) {
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (check == true){
            b.setText("FALSE");
            check = false; //HERE IS THE ERROR
        }
        else{

        }
    }
});
}
```

you call b.setOnClickListener(**new** ...)  <-- this `new` creates an implicit anonymous instance of a class that implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface.
You can verify, that the OnClickListener is an interface by simply pressing Ctrl-B while the text cursor is somewhere on the word `OnClickListener`. This takes you to the declaration of any item below the cursor.

And as it is a **new** *something*, it's a new instance and therefore not the same class/instance where your method `public void setButton...` is.

In Java, if you access a variable or parameter declared in an *outer* class (where your setButton(...) is) from an *inner* class (your click listener) they have to be final. In other words: read-only.

To solve your problem, I would suggest you use `b.setChecked` the same way you use `b.setText` and assign the checked state directly to the button.
You also *read* the checked state of the button by calling `b.isChecked` and you just eliminate the parameter `check` entirely. You don't need it.

So, your working method would look like:

```
public void setButton(final Button b) {
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (b.isChecked()){
                b.setText("FALSE");
                b.setChecked(false);
            }
            else{

            }
         }
    });
}
```

and even more easily, if you just want, that your button swaps its checked state whenever you click it (true/false/true/false...), it would look like this:

```
public void setButton(final Button b) {
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setChecked(!b.isChecked());
            b.setText(String.valueOf(b.isChecked());
         }
    });
}
```

What does this do?

```
b.setChecked(!b.isChecked());
```

In human words: "Set the checked of the button to NOT its current checked state". So if its true, it will be false, and vice-versa.

Well, and the .setText is no black magic either. Just print the boolean value.
String.valueOf(any_boolean) will return "true" or "false".

Hope this helps you understanding.

**Edit**
As you mentioned correctly, a `Button` can not be `checked`. If you *need* a Button from you GUI, you can derive your own to achieve that.

```
public class CheckButton extends Button {
    private boolean checked = false;
    public boolean isChecked { return checked; }
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) { this.checked = checked; }
}
```

Then modify your XML's to use `CheckButton` instead of `Button` and your method to take a `final CheckButton b` as parameter.

Comment: I used the regular Button, and i get an error saying that it cannot resolve the method setChecked and isChecked

Comment: You are right. A ``Button`` can not be checked. Use a ``CheckBox`` instead. Sorry.
Or you derive your own Button class from Button and extend it with a ``checked`` field. I updated my answer to show you the code.